# is there a way that can concat either a list or a string to another list?

Tags: python

I have function that will basically add a list of string to beginning of a variable. But the variable can be either a string or a list. e.g.

```
a = ['left', 'right']   # error if a = 'left'
b = ['unnamed' for i in range(2)]
a = b + a
```

However, I would like to let users to make a string as well when there is only one element. So instead of `['left']`, you can just input `'left'`. This however, will raise error at `a = b + a` of course.

Is there a way that can be flexible enough to do both. Or I would have to use `if else` to separate the two cases.

Comment: Just a note: for the list comprehension you can also do `['unnamed' for _ in range(2)]`, because you don't use the `i`

Answer (score 2):

you check the type and convert to a list if it's a string

```
a = ['left', 'right']   # error if a = 'left'
b = ['unnamed' for i in range(2)]

if type(a) == str: 
    a = [a]

a = b + a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to transform the string to array. If it's already an array `np.array` will increase the dimensionality, hence the need to `flatten()`. After that you can use sets in order to combine the two lists togerher.

```
import numpy as np

arr = ['a', 'b']
arr1 = ['g']
string = 'h'

print(list(set(arr).union(set(np.array(string).flatten()))))
# ['a', 'b', 'h']
print(list(set(arr).union(set(np.array(arr1).flatten()))))
# ['a', 'b', 'g']
```

**EDIT:**

You can achieve the same with the addition operator, but you'll need to apply `tolist()` in order to transform the numpy array into a python list.

```
print(arr + np.array(string).flatten().tolist())
# ['a', 'b', 'h']
print(arr + np.array(arr1).flatten().tolist())
# ['a', 'b', 'g']
```

Comment: Hi! Please explain why this is a solution to OPs code as code only answers are discouraged on SO. This would help OP and future visitors to the site. Thanks!